# I am getting these errors in laravel while running existing project file on my localhost

Tags: php, laravel, require-once

> Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\skillrashtra/public/index.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\skillrashtra\server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\skillrashtra/public/index.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\skillrashtra\server.php on line 21

I have tried all these commands in order to solve this but didn't work.

```
composer update 
copy .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: is there file in  C:\xampp\htdocs\skillrashtra/public/index.php     Also try this php artisan serve

Comment: looks like you mixed unix with win path slash format.
try this: require_once(C:/xampp/htdocs/skillrashtra/public/index.php)

Comment: do you actually have an `index.php` in your `public` folder?